# NavigationLink is not working in fullScreenCover when I click item in list

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I want to show a list in fullscreenCover and navigate another View from there but unfortunately when I click Items in list nothing happens. If anyone can help, I would be happy...
here is example code

```
 Button("New Message"){
        shownFCover.toggle()
    }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $shownFCover) {
        VStack {
            Button("Close"){
                shownFCover.toggle()
            }
            List {
                ForEach(0..<16) { index in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Hello")
                    } label: {
                        HStack{
                            Image(systemName: "\(index).circle.fill").font(.title).foregroundColor(.red)
                            
                            Text("\(index). Item")
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.sheet` and `.fullScreenCover` introduce new presentations, so we need new `NavigationView` inside

```
Button("New Message"){
        shownFCover.toggle()
    }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $shownFCover) {
        VStack {
            Button("Close"){
                shownFCover.toggle()
            }
          NavigationView {        // << here !!
            List {
                ForEach(0..<16) { index in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Hello")
                    } label: {
                        HStack{
                            Image(systemName: "\(index).circle.fill").font(.title).foregroundColor(.red)
                            
                            Text("\(index). Item")
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
          }
        }
}
```

*Note: I recommend to separate full screen content into standalone view instead of having all right there.

So it would look like

```
Button("New Message"){
        shownFCover.toggle()
    }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $shownFCover) {
       FCoverView(shownCover: $shownFCover)
    }
```